# Which phrase is more common or do the two phrases have different intentions?

Tags: meaning-in-context, connotation

> `Not all people` are hard-working.
>   `Not everyone` is hard-working.

Comment: "Not everyone" makes better sense and is logically more correct in the context. Note that  "Not all people" may be a better choice in a different kind of sentence/ context. It's not about grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the context. *Everyone* is defined as "every person" (Cambridge Dictionaries Online), *people* as "human beings in general or considered collectively" or "used to refer to everyone, or informally to the group that you are speaking to". (Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

So, the meaning of *people* has more connotations with collectivity while *everyone* is related more to a group/bunch of separate individuals.

Comment: +1 You got a point there. Try to substantiate with some references to strengthen your argument. Good Luck.